# Running a flask app that uses tensorflow on an Ubuntu 16.04 instance on GCP, model runs but predictions are different than on local host

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, huggingface-transformers

I trained a BERT model using huggingface for tensorflow on my localhost. Running predictions on my localhost works fine.

I then implemented a solution so I can call my model from a GCP VM instance (Ubuntu 16.04) via flask. The process seems to work as I can successfully make the calls to my app on the VM.

However, the prediction I receive from the VM differs from the one I receive on my localhost (which is the expected output), yet I use identical code. I use a model for Sequence Classification, and when trying to get the probabilities for both labels on my localhost I get: `array([0.67829543, 0.32170454], dtype=float32)` while the VM returns `array([1, 1], dtype=float32)`.
This snippet is what I use to predict the model just for reference:

```
predict_input = tokenizer.encode(sentence,
                                  truncation=True,
                                  padding=True,
                                  return_tensors="tf"
                                  )
tf_output = model.predict(predict_input)[0]
    
tf_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf_output, axis=0).numpy()
```

On my localhost I trained the model using tf with GPU support, the VM of course only has two vCPUs. When loading tensorflow on the VM I get the following warnings:

```
2020-12-27 07:57:55.533847: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.1'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-12-27 07:57:55.533896: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2020-12-27 07:57:56.792914: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-12-27 07:57:56.792966: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:312] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-12-27 07:57:56.793002: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (bertvm-1): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2020-12-27 07:57:56.793316: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 A
VX512F FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-12-27 07:57:56.801469: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:104] CPU Frequency: 2000129999 Hz
2020-12-27 07:57:56.801693: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x64b8fe0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-12-27 07:57:56.801805: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
```

I'm not sure if that is the root of the error or if it's because I trained the model using tf for GPU and am predicting on an instance that runs tf for CPU but that doesn't seem to make too much sense to me.
The warnings only seem to pertain to CUDA 'issues' which I believe is related to GPU support.

Any idea or tips as to what could be the cause of the different predictions?
Thanks for your help in advance!

EDIT:
It seems that the model returns the same logits on both, the VM and the localhost. When I then apply `tf.nn.softmax(tf_output, axis=0).numpy()` I get different results.
tf_output being `[1.9530067 1.2070574]` on both instances while the above function returns `[0.67829543 0.32170454]` on localhost and `[[1. 1.]]` on the VM (both formatted here as a string) as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the issue.

`tf_output = model.predict(predict_input)` didn't behave the same way on my VM (that runs Python 3.5 btw, while my localhost runs python 3.8). Somehow I had to index twice on the VM while on my localhost one index was enough.
So `tf_output = model.predict(predict_input)[0]` on the localhost turns into `tf_output = model.predict(predict_input)[0][0]` on the VM.

Similarily, calling `.numpy()` on `tf.nn.softmax(tf_output, axis=0).numpy()` worked on the localhost, while on the VM it was ignored.
Replacing `tf_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf_output, axis=0).numpy()` with

```
tf_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf_output, axis=0).numpy()
tf_prediction = tf_prediction.numpy()
```

solved my issue in combination with the above.

Here's the final snippet that works on the VM just for clarity:

```
tf_output = model.predict(predict_input)[0][0]
tf_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf_output, axis=0).numpy()
tf_prediction = tf_prediction.numpy()
```

The VM runs on Ubuntu 16.04, with TF 2.3.1, python 3.5 without GPU while my localhost runs on Windows 10 with TF 2.4.0, python 3.8 and a GPU if that matters.

Seems somewhat illogical to me tbh but I suppose it's at the least a workaround.
Hope my monologue contributes to someone else's issue as well^^ Cheers.